# Assign domain name to azure VM

Tags: azure, dns

Im trying to assign my domain name to my azure virtual machine, been reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip but I dont have a static IP. So I should be using CNAME?

At my domain name register I have added:

```
DNS ENTRY   TYPE    PRIORITY    TTL DESTINATION/TARGET  
www         CNAME               mydomain.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com
```

I want it to work as mydomain.com (without www) - but not resolving. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can change you public IP to a static one without disruption your VM at all (so it continues to opérate). That solves one part of the problem.

The other way of doing this is exactly what you specified. CName link your Azure DNS to your real dns.

Comment: Yes, did cname method - how do I test it? Or just have to wait 24 hours?

Comment: well, that depends on your dns provider, for me it generally works right away